# If you report your employer for wage theft, do you have to provide evidence you hold no shares and therefore FLSA applies?

Tags: united-states, labor-law, workplace

If you report your employer for wage theft, do you have to provide evidence you hold no shares and therefore FLSA applies?

How do you convince your manager to confirm you have no shares without making them suspect your building evidence you're reporting them?